# Twilio - Display the originally dialled number

Tags: twilio

I have several businesses with different phone numbers but want to answer all calls from the one phone line which uses caller ID to display the original number dialled, prior to being diverted, so we can answer the call in the correct business name.
For example, a person dials X (Business A) which is diverted to Y (Business B). When the call comes in to Y, the caller ID displays X (the name of the original business name dialled, in this case Business A). Then we can answer the call "Good morning, Business A). This would be replicated for 5 different businesses all coming in to the one line.
This will save us from installing several phone lines. I believe this must be possible but would greatly appreciate confirmation of this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Are you talking about using the business' original phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can set callerID during call divert (DIAL).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+1XXXXXXXXXXX">
        <Number>+1YYYYYYYYYY</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

For more https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id

Comment: This requires multiple twilio numbers(one for each number); whereas i am looking for using one twilio number for all the clients. I want to find out the dialled Id and then display it to the agent so that he can speak with the person suitably.